# Parenting bones to character mesh

Tags: rigging, armature

[image]
Hi everyone , 
      I am having trouble parenting my armature to my actual character mesh. I select the mesh, shift right click on any bone in the armature and hit Ctrl P and add with automatic weights. My whole mesh is mirrored and only stretches and deforms on the mirrored side Hand but everything else is completely fine and functional. Any help would be appreciated thanks.

Blend:
[image]

Comment: do you still have the mirror modifier on the mesh? Because the rig will **not** work with a mirror modifier.

Comment: could you provide your .blend file to be able to help you?

Comment: Yes I did. I deleted it then added the parent and added another mirror modifier and it had a better effect but I still have clipping and merge enabled and the mesh divides in half when I move the character around. But the hand was normal again.

Comment: How would I be able to do that Tak?

Comment: I also tried to delete the mirror, Shift D to copy my one side then S key then X key -1 to scale it across the X axis evenly and it still had the messed up finger effect to it

Comment: Please upload it through this link http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com

Comment: I tried to add it not sure if it did though

Comment: It should not be necessary to delete the mirror modifier so long as it is above the armature modifier and has the vertex groups box checked. Your problem in the image looks like a combination of bad automatic weights and/or improperly setup bone constraints, but without a blend its pretty hard to say exactly what is wrong

Comment: [<img src="http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/embedImage.png?bid=2524" />](http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/b/2524/)

Comment: i figured out i had to apply pose to rest pose and it fixed my problem. problem now is i tweaked around some other settings and have new problem with the tip of the fingers that i don't know what i did to it

Comment: @user34518 I've provided an answer to your initial question so if you could accept it. And I just saw that you are facing another problem, could you provide a link of the updated file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that your rest pose is different from your pose position. To fix this:

1. Switch to Pose Mode
2. Select all Bones with <kbd>A</kbd>
3. Hit <kbd>Space bar</kbd>
4. Select `Apply Pose as Rest Pose`
5. Switch to object Mode
6. Select Your mesh first then select the armature using <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Right Mouse Click</kbd>
7. Hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd> then choose Automatic Weighting and this will fix your problem as shown below

[image]

Comment: Thanks Tak. Was your mesh fully functional after?

Comment: Yes it was. If you faced any other problem as you said after changing some settings then could you ask another question and provide your updated .blend file and send me a link of your new question here?

Comment: Here it is http://blender.stackexchange.com/q/71206/34518

Comment: sorry I forgot to @ you

Comment: @user34518 no worries, I've provided an answer for your problem