# My armature is not effecting the right arm of my mesh

Tags: rigging, armature

I had a problem last night with my armature having a very weird deform which was answered by having to apply pose at rest pose. before knowing that i was tweaking around with some of the settings and now i have no idea what i did to get it back to normal. my right [image]

Comment: [<img src="http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/embedImage.png?bid=2523" />](http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/b/2523/)

Comment: Did you mirror your right armature? If so then you have to rename the bones.

Comment: @bunnybot5555 yes I did . Right now I selected my right arm bones and flipped the names but I am still having the problem

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to apply your mirror modifier of your mesh before parenting.

This is the steps I did:

1. Go to the mirror mesh modifier and apply it
2. Go to to the vertex groups and delete all groups as shown:
   [image]
3. Select Mesh then armature then hit <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd> and automatic weighting

This is the result after these steps:

[image]

The updated .blend file can be found here: [image]